# Issue with In-App Purchase in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, in-app-purchase

I have launched my app on AppStore which includes In-App purchase feature. In-App was working fine in iOS5,iOS6 and iOS7 in sandbox mode. But after App Store approval, In-App is not working in iOS7 devices sometimes. Sometimes In-App is not working first time, When second time when user click on buys it works. What is the issue? Its working fine in iOS5 and iOS6 devices. Can anyone explains and share any solution.

Answer (score 0):

this is also happening for past few days on all iOS's. Most of the time it gives same message on device as well. Though I have I know the code I have does not any issue and when I submitted to app and it is approved, it works perfectly. It looks like some issue with sandbox env.

Comment: No my app is working perfect in sandbox mode. But after approval its causing error.